# Insert and Select rows with high character count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting data into a nvarchar(max) or ntext column, the string lengths are around 130,000 characters. When I insert the data and then copy the row out of the grid, it only ever represents the first 43,700 characters of the insert. So what I need is a way where all 130,000 characters are stored in the row because both these data types should be capable of storing that size of string.

Using just the 43,700 character rows that my inserts have created, I attempted to select the row with 'results to file' on because this is what I will be doing with the rows is outputting them to a report file (one report file for each 130,00 character row). Unfortunately, only the first 8192 characters of the row are shown in the report file, I had been into options and set the output to max which is 8192 characters. So what I will need here is a way where, when the 130,000 characters are stored in the row, all of them can be output to file.

I know that there are ways of coding SQL so it splits up the insert into three rows and then splits the select into however many parts will be necessary to output all the data. By doing that tho', are we saying that with data types capable of holding a million or more characters, SSMS is only able to insert 43,700 characters and output only 8192 characters. Or, is there a way of setting the server / database / table to enable it to use the given capacity of these datatypes?

Thanks in advance to any solutions.

Comment: How and from what platform are you inserting/querying your data? It certainly works when done via ADO.NET for example.

Comment: Well I am just working with raw data pasted onto query analyser and then using an insert statement and surrounding the data with the single quote marks.

Comment: I doubt that is ever going to work because SMSS is not designed for application level operations. It could just as easy be a limitation of Windows Clipboard.

Comment: For sure all the data shows up in the query analyser when I first paste it on so I would doubt it is the clip-board...Unless you're referring to copying it out of the row. If all the data is in the row then it would just be a question of surmounting the issue of the max 8192 characters to file.

Comment: If, @DaleBurrell no one's going to come up with a way round the setting it will just need to be a substring query. (thx).